# a Bostonian poet

Tags: meaning, prepositions

a. He is a poet of Boston.

b. He is a Bostonian poet.

c. He is a poet from Boston.

What is the differences in the meanings of those sentences?

I think in (a), he writes about Boston. He might not even have been born there.

(b) and (c) mean virtually the same to me, but if he is still in Boston, then I'd use (b).

I think (c) might give the impression that he is somewhere else, but maybe that's only me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sentence (a) is unnatural and ambiguous. It could mean he's from Boston, or it could mean he writes about Boston.

Sentence (b) and (c) mean roughly the same thing, but (b) has a nuance of a stronger roots in the city, like probably born and raised there, while in (c) he might have moved there after childhood, so is technically "from Boston".

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply (and the other ones as well). So even if he is in Boston right now, I could still use (c), right?

Comment: Yes. In that context, "from" would indicate where he lives, which is Boston.

Comment: If he has moved out of Boston, you might say "originally from Boston".

Comment: US native-speaker and 14-year Boston resident here.  I don't think I've ever heard or seen Bostonian used as an adjective, so (b) sounds strange.    I think this is just a quirk with Bostonian, as there are plenty of other versions of (b) that sound fine such as  "He is a Canadian poet." or "He is a Californian poet".

Comment: Re. (b): if you didn't know otherwise, you might assume that ‘Bostonian’ referred to a style, period, or genre of poetry, in the same way that a poet might be  [Augustan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustan_literature), [Heptanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptanese_School_(literature)), or [Nuyorican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuyorican_Poets_Caf%C3%A9).